# intuition about Gaussian processes over a finite space

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, it.information-theory, metric-embeddings, information-geometry

In a paper that I am reading the authors defines $\mathbb P(n,q)$ the space of covariance **tensors** for $\mathbb R^q$-valued Gaussian processes on an abstract finite space $K=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. In his whole paper he then works on the "state space"
$$
{\cal S}_q=\Big\{(u,L)\in (\mathbb R^q)^n\times \mathbb P(n,q)\Big\}.
$$
(I presume this is some kind of statistical manifold?)
One of the purposes of the paper is to discuss somehow "metric embeddings" of $K$ (with some discrete distance) in $\mathbb R^q$, so the geometric framework really matters and I would like to get as much intuition as possible on this state space. However I am familiar neither with probability nor with information theory, and I am struggling to figure out whether this point of view is different from a simple $\mathbb R^{nq}$-valued multivariate normal distribution? If, as I believe, this is really the same space, I imagin that the author's choice of **tensoring out** $(\mathbb R^q)^n$ instead of taking the apparently simpler point of view on $\mathbb R^{nq}$-valued random variables aims at conveying some geometrical insights. In other words, if I chose to work in the $\mathbb R^{nq}$ setting, am I only merely choosing to work "in coordinates" on $\cal S_q$, or am I missing something deeper?

I do realize that this is not a proper question calling for a precise and rigorous answer, this is more a meta-question asking for philosophical points of view. If you think that math.SE is better suited for this question please feel free to migrate.